# CodeIgniter URL Route with ID and title

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Im new to CodeIgniter and
I would like to change my URL from

http://test.com/1/test-post

to

http://test.com/test-post-1

in CI with route. How can i achieve this with URL Route ?

**My Table Posts**

```
posts_id
posts_name
```

**My Home View** (to call the posts)

Im using url title for the url:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url("{$v['posts_id']}/".url_title($v['posts_name'], "-", true)) ?>">
```

**My Posts Controller**

```
    <?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed');
class Posts extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Posts_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        show_404();
    }
    public function details($posts_id=NULL,$posts_name='') {
        $data['title'] = $this->Posts_model->select_content_by_id($posts_id);
        $data['data'] = $this->Posts_model->select_content_by_id($posts_id);
        $this->load->view('posts',$data);
    }
}
```

**My Posts Model**

```
 <?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed');
class Posts_model extends CI_Model{
    public function dsPosts()
    {
        return $this->db->get('posts')->result_array();
    }
    public function select_content_by_id($posts_id)
    {
        return $this->db->where('posts_id',$posts_id)->get('posts')->result_array();
    }
}
```

**My Route**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(:num)'] = 'posts/details/$1';
$route['(:num)/(:any)'] = 'posts/details/$1/$2';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are near to the answer

```
$route['(:any)-(:num)'] = 'posts/details/$2/$1';
```

then in view

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(url_title($v['posts_name'], "-", true)."-{$v['posts_id']}".) ?>">
```

That's all. But I suggest you write more clearly urls because you can have more than one controller! What happens if you have *comments* controller and want to get data from it? *(:any)* means it can be whatever

Comment: Thanks ! Its worked. I forgot to check the input id... so i made a mistakes with $1 and $2 !!